# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection while loading and storing Blob data

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, oracle11g, blob

Whenever I try to upload a blob image to database or fetch a blob image from the database it gives me this warning.

At start upload to database was working, but after stopping the server and restarting it, even the upload function is not working.

What is the problem? How to Solve it?

**Console**

> ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush
>   [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access blob stream]
>           Aug 15, 2018 8:58:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
>           INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
>           org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Unable to access blob stream; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access blob stream
>             at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:621)
>                 at     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>             at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>             at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
>        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>             at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>             at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
>             at 
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>           Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access blob stream
>             at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BlobTypeDescriptor.unwrap(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:138)
>             at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BlobTypeDescriptor.unwrap(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:33)
>             at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3154)
>             at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3077)
>             at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3457)
>             at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145)
>             at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:599)
>             at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:473)
>             at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>             at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>             at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437)
>             at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493)
>             at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3207)
>             at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2413)
>             at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:609)
>             ... 48 more
>           Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
>             at oracle.sql.BLOB.getDBAccess(BLOB.java:1071)
>             at oracle.sql.BLOB.getBinaryStream(BLOB.java:248)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>             at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.SerializableBlobProxy.invoke(SerializableBlobProxy.java:60)
>             at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.getBinaryStream(Unknown Source)
>             at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BlobTypeDescriptor.unwrap(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:117)
>             ... 74 more